# How to pass datetime variable from C# code to java webservice?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, datetime-format

```
getClients(LoginInfo user, long sysId, java.lang.String accNum, java.lang.String ClientNum, java.util.Calendar fromTime, java.util.Calendar toTime, boolean showDeactivated, boolean showDetails).
```

Above is java webservice method that I am calling from C# code.

I am passing fromTime and ToTime parameters with following values

```
 DateTime from = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
 DateTime to = new DateTime(2012, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Found an error **`date string can not be less than 19 charactors`**

Edit_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
**Below is method in proxy**

```
getClients([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] 
LoginInfo user, long sysId, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] bool sysdSpecified, 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] string accNum, 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] 
string ClientNum, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] 
System.Nullable<System.DateTime> fromTime, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] bool fromTimeSpecified,
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] System.Nullable<System.DateTime> toTime,
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] 
bool toTimeSpecified, 
bool showDeactivated, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
 bool showDeactivatedSpecified, bool showDetails, 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] bool showDetailsSpecified) {
}
```

Comment: How about 6 strings. Year, month etc.

Comment: what does your proxy look like?

Comment: @lukas.Same error with this  DateTime format.    DateTime from = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you convert the value to a long? For example: minutes from 01/01/1990.

Comment: ` DateTime from = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1);
  DateTime dtFromLong = new DateTime(from.Ticks);` I am now passing dtFromLong instead of from and found same error.Could you please elobrate this

Comment: The web service is expecting DateTime, so that's what you must provide. So this is not a correct approach. I would give -1, if I was allowed...

Comment: you can try somethinh like:
            //sender
            var yourDate = DateTime.Now;
            var elapsed = yourDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1990, 01, 01)).Ticks;


            //listener
            var receiveDate = new DateTime(1990, 01, 01).AddTicks(elapsed);

Answer (score 2):

Send from C# as:

```
private static readonly DateTime Jan1st1970 = new DateTime
    (1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static long CurrentTimeMillis()
{
    return (long) (DateTime.UtcNow - Jan1st1970).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Recieve in Java as:

`new Date(longValueFromAbove);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DateTimeKind.UTC?

The string is probably missing the time zone specifier, when you use DateTimeKind.Unspecified.

EDIT: OK, DateTime is not providing the timezone by any means, but DateTimeOffset does it. Try this:

```
  new DateTimeOffset(yourDateTime)
```

Comment: I already checked this option 'DateTimeKind.UTC' which is also not working,I Tried many day format no one succeeded

Comment: Have you tried the DateTimeOffset already? Sorry I did not add a comment in time, so you probably did not notice my edit.